# Why isn't this attempt to log into reddit using superagent on Node.js successful?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reddit, superagent

Here's the most minimal test case that I could reduce. It may help to convert it to use native Node HTTP or else use the request library, if you're more familiar with either one of those. But as is, I get back a bunch of jquery crap. AFAICT, the HTTP POST request sent is identical to the one programmed in curl here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15169425/3025492

```
var USER = 'uuuut',
    PASS = 'ppppt';
superagent
    .post( 'https://pay.reddit.com/api/login/' )
    .send( { api_type: 'json', rem: 'True',
              user: USER, passwd: PASS } )
    .end( function( res ) {
      console.log( 'Session cookie: ', res.body.data.cookie || res.headers['Set-Cookie'] );
    });
```

When done correctly, it's just supposed to set an authentication cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problem in your code:

1. the post request in `form` instead of `json`, so you need the method `.type('form')`
2. the returned cookie at: `res.body.json.data.cookie`
3. headers in superagent must be in lower case: `res.headers['set-cookie']`

Full code:

```
superagent
    .post( 'https://pay.reddit.com/api/login/' )
    .type('form') // send request in form format
    .send( { api_type: 'json', rem: 'True',
              user: USER, passwd: PASS } )
    .end( function(err, res) {
      console.log( 'Session cookie: ', res.body.json.data.cookie || res.headers['set-cookie']);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I''ll give this a try a little later.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at the rest of the script? It's getting some weirdly encoded or garbled text back which it's totally choking on... https://gist.github.com/bmproc/bdcd926c875597e3246b If you could figure out what the problem is, I'd very much appreciate it. Thanks, @damphat

Comment: Don't really know what you are trying to do! But I just remove proxy setting and stringify body then it work and print a bunch of json files: https://gist.github.com/damphat/079820bea8b3a53bdc53 .

Comment: The problem is that the printed files are corrupt.. I fixed it by removing the gzip/deflate line.